# Определить, что точка входит в RectTransform

Tags: c#, unity3d

Столкнулся с проблемой - не могу определить находится ли точка в ui элементе. Мне необходимо после совершения какого-либо действия проверить, находится ли мышка в ui элементе. Для этого я хотел использовать данный код. Но столкнулся с проблемой. Width в RectTransform остается неизменным при изменении экрана, высота меняется а вот ширина нет. Соответственно данный код не работает

Сама функция

```
public bool In(Vector3 position, RectTransform originalParent)
{
    return originalParent.rect.Contains(new Vector2(position.x, -position.y));
}
```

Вызывается функция

```
if (In(Input.mousePosition, _inventory))
{

}
```

где _inventory - это Viewport содержащийся в ScrollView

Comment: Так известны текущие координаты и размеру прямоугольника или нет?

Comment: Странность заключается в том, что при изменении экрана, высота  меняется, а ширина остается неизменной. Видимо я чего то не понимаю

Answer (score 0):

Если у тебя подключен интерфейс на мышь, то в методе этого интерфейса ты делаешь проверку
 `if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()) { ... }` и туда уже суешь код.

Comment: Я думал об этом способе. Однако я не нашел, как можно вытащить над каким именно объектом UI находится мышка

Comment: попробуй использовать `EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject` и обратится к `.name`. Сам не проверял, но вдруг сработает ¯ \ _ (ツ) _ / ¯. Если что он имеет тип GameObject [ссылка](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem-currentSelectedGameObject.html)

Comment: К сожалению, это не помогло, мне null выдается. Наверное стоит описать более подробно. Я реализую инвентарь. И хочу чтобы при перемещении объекта со сцены в инвентарь он уничтожался. Но не могу решить проблемы с тем чтобы при отпускании кнопки мыши, была проверка находится ли объект в пределах инвентаря.

Comment: Для проверки, что объект находится над ui-кой, нужна проверка:


 `if (EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())` 


Тебе нужно удалять объект со сцены? Есть ли у тебя база? И где висит скрипт с перетаскиванием? Нужен твой способ реализации инвентаря. Можешь в свой вопрос добавить скрины, как это выглядит